# iTunes Connect - How can I get a properly-sized screenshot?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, screenshot

I am trying to release a production build of my app in the iTunes Connect interface.

I'm required to upload screenshots. When I run my app in the simulator, hitting Cmd+S produces a screenshot in 750x1334. When I attempt to upload that to iTunes Connect, I get an error message saying:

> The dimensions of one or more of screenshots are wrong. [**Learn More**](https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/devd274dd925)

That Learn More link takes me to some cryptic table which still doesn't tell me how can I get a properly-sized screenshot.

Any idea how can I get a screenshot with exactly the required dimensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you've uploaded the screenshot from a 4.7 inch iPhone in the section which is shown by default (it's 5.8" Display at the moment). You have to upload the correctly sized screenshot to the correct screen size section.

First, press the button on the right called **View All Sizes in Media Manager**.

[image: "View All Sizes in Media Manager" button]

After that, scroll down to the **4.7" Display** section and uncheck **Use 5.5" Display** on the right.

[image: "Use 5.5" Display" option unchecked]

Finally, press the **Choose File** button at the bottom or drag & drop your screenshots to that area.

[image: "Choose File" button]

---

Keep in mind that only screenshots of 5.5 inch iPhones are **mandatory** if you have iPhone as a target. Also, you have to include screenshots from a 12.9 inch iPad Pro if your app targets iPads. All other sizes are **optional**.

[image: mandatory screen sizes]

Comment: Why don't they just list which devices are which size in that stupid table? It already has enough extraneous info. That would have been actually helpful.

Comment: For the record, using the iPhone 8 Plus simulator, and doing Cmd+S generated the properly-sized screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

First you need at least a 6 plus simulator running, they have the resolution Apple will accept.
If you are already running a 6 plus simulator you have to press Cmd+1 (or Window>Scale>100%) while on the simulator so it has no scaling on it and then you can Cmd+S to generate the screenshot.